How to set refresh rate for grub menu?
My laptop screen is broken, it keeps flickering when it is set to 144Hz but works fine when it is set to 60Hz. So I want to limit my grub menu to 60Hz but I'm unable to get it to work.
Following is the grub menu configuration file I have:
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || ec>
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=1920x1080@60"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

I dont see any difference after setting the video to 1920x1080@60. What am I doing wrong?

Did you run sudo update-grub after editing /etc/default/grub?
